# Error during execution - 9 subscript out of range

Tags: vbscript, automated-tests

When I call this from the automated script it fails saying "9 subscript out of range"

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook =      objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\docstore\testinganywhere\spreadsheets\ccm_cases.xls")
Dim myVar
Dim dataArray
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments


'objArgs Sample Data = "LNK^CPRSDONOTUSER,ONE 5018^06/01/2010 09:00^CHECKED OUT^NSC, VA PENSION^X^XRAY^474-TROY^CPRSPHYSICIAN,ONE^No patient insurance data on file.^No entry on file.^NA^No visit notes on file.^CPRSPHYSICIAN,ONE^LEGAL REFERRED TO CODING^NORMAL^10/22/2013 14:09^09/29/2010 14:33^99215;99214;84443;88000^074.0;V08.;305.1^X^X^X^X^UR^URComment^Not Vested"

msgbox objArgs(0)
dataArray = Split(objArgs(0),"^")
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = 0
workSheetCount = objExcel.Worksheets.Count
Dim visitDateTime
Dim patientName


patientName = dataArray(1)

'The script fails after here
visitDateTime = dataArray(2)
```

Even though I know that I am passing in a very long string the only thing that is shown in the "msgbox objArgs(0)" is "LNK^CPRSDONOTUSER,ONE". It seems to have something to do with the space between "ONE" and "5018".

How can I get this entire string passed in?

Comment: Try something like `Const scriptArgs as String = "LNK^CPRSDONOTUSER,ONE 5018^06/01/2010 09:00^CHECKED OUT^NSC, VA PENSION^X^XRAY^474-TROY^CPRSPHYSICIAN,ONE^No patient insurance data on file.^No entry on file.^NA^No visit notes on file.^CPRSPHYSICIAN,ONE^LEGAL REFERRED TO CODING^NORMAL^10/22/2013 14:09^09/29/2010 14:33^99215;99214;84443;88000^074.0;V08.;305.1^X^X^X^X^UR^URComment^Not Vested"` and then `objArgs Sample Data = scriptArgs`?

Comment: How do you call the script?